# what is the "Value" when define a enum

Tags: scala

I'm a newbie learning scala, can anyone plz explain what is the "Value" keyword here. Does it a property of object or something else?

```
object Color extends Enumeration {
  val Red, Green, Orange, Black = Value
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.8/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L160

Answer (score 6):

`Value` is a protected method defined in the `Enumeration` class. It creates an instance of the `Value` type that's also defined in the `Enumeration` class.

Comment: So, if you are coming from Java, what this does is basically `val Red : Color.Value = Color.createInstanceWithNextNumber(); val Green : Color.Value = Color.createInstanceWithNextNumber(); `

Comment: Note that in  `val a,b,c = x`, the `x` is evaluated three times. That's how your `Red` and `Green` end up with a different value even though it looks like they are assigned to the same thing.